# Listview выделяет только со второго раза

Tags: java, android, menu

Добрый вечер! Я реализовал боковое меню с помощью [этой библиотеки](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)
Для отображения пунктов меню я использую Listview. При нажатии на один из элементов этого ListView он должен визуально изменяться (должен измениться фон элемента). Все вроде бы работает хорошо за исключением одного момента: выделение элемента появляется только после второго нажатия. То есть если кликнуть по пункту меню один раз, то выделение появляется, но если после этого скрыть меню методом toggle() а затем снова его открыть (тем же методом toggle либо методом showMenu) то выделение пропадает. Но если нажать на элемент снова то выделение уже никуда не пропадает даже если скрыть и снова показать меню. С чем это может быть связано может кто знает?

Answer (score 3):

Это скорее всего связано с тем, что логика отрисовки графики использует главный поток. При первом касании оно отисовало(не вывело на екран потому-что главный екран не обновлялся), но при втором вызове уже отрисовалось (обновился главный екран). Нужно юзать AsyncTask, он может работать с UI используя другой поток.